# sqlite: alias column name can't contains a dot "."

Tags: sql, sqlite

(sorry for my poor english)

If you try this select operation over a sqlite database:

> SELECT column AS 'alias 1' FROM table;

You get the expected column name:

```
alias 1
--------
result 1
result 2
```

but if your alias contains a dot "." ... you get a wrong column name:

> SELECT column AS 'alias.1' FROM table;

```
1
--------
result 1
result 2
```

(all behind the dot is ommited in the column name)

Wow...
It's weird...

anyone can help me?

thank you very much

**UPDATE:**

maybe it's just a bug in SQLiteStudio  (the software where I'm testing my queries) and in QT (they both doesn't expect dots in alias names but sqlite does)

Answer (score 13):

Enclose your alias in double quotes.

```
SELECT 'test' AS "testing.this"
```

Output:

```
| testing.this |
  test
```

**Updated:**
Double quotes are used to enclose identifiers in SQL, not single quotes. Single quotes are only for strings. In this case you are trying to ensure that "testing.this" is used as is and not confused as testing.this (`testing` table `this` column).

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24

Comment: no... that doesn't works. SQlite uses single quotes for that.

Comment: I ran the query...it works amazing or I wouldn't have given you an output.

Comment: I believe in your word Kevin... but it doesn't work for me... please, if you can, try your query in this software http://sqlitestudio.one.pl (anyway it doesn't work in my c++ software)

Comment: It is likely a limitation in your API and software then. I'd log a bug there.

Answer (score 5):

Use backticks

```
SELECT column AS `alias.1` FROM table;
```

Or double quotes (ANSI standard) per the other answer

```
SELECT column AS "alias.1" FROM table;
```

Both verified in SQLite Manager for FireFox

Comment: no... that doesnt works.. put in this way `alias.1` ... and you don't get the expected column name...

Comment: I thought backticks are a MySQL extension to double quote usage?The SQL standard is for double quotes is it not?

Comment: @Kevin both work. @Javi - where are you running the query from?

Comment: over SQLiteStudio and in my qt software

Comment: @Javi Given that new nugget - your workaround is all there is. Nice finding it. I'd file a bug report

Answer (score 1):

Definitely working properly:

```
C:\Windows>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.7.8 2011-09-19 14:49:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> SELECT 'hello' AS 'alias.1';
alias.1
----------
hello
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the SQLite 3 then the following query works just fine with various types used for the Alias column names.

See the result below the query:

```
select '1' as 'my.Col1', '2' as "my.Col2", '3' as [my.Col3], '4' as [my Col4] , '5' as 'my Col5'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a "fix"...

> SELECT column AS '.alias.1' FROM
>   table;

```
alias.1
--------
result 1
result 2
```

just another dot in the begining...

of course I don't like this solution...
any other idea??

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, it works on Hive

```
select 1 as `xxx.namewith.dot`
```

`xxx.` means any word you want to input with dot notation on latest

`namewith.dot` means any alias name with dot notation on it