# Update column with a string if t1.column is equal to t2.column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have this query in `php mysql`

`UPDATE person a, activity b SET value="attended" WHERE a.name = b.name`

It works fine on php mysql. But how do i do this query in android sqlite? I know its kind of different approach when using android sqlite.

What i've tried is this but it produces error

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE person a, activity b SET value='attended' WHERE a.name = b.name");
```

What is the proper way for this query? please help

This is the error i get

`Sqlite exception: near "a": syntax error (code 1): while compiling: UPDATE person a, activity b SET value='attended' WHERE a.name = b.name`

So i've got rid of the aliases and used this one instead

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE person SET value= (SELECT name FROM activity WHERE person.name = acitivty.name");
```

It returns a name of updated values.

Does it normally outputs `null` if the row is not updated / doesnt have same value from other table?

```
 | column    | 
 -------------
 | Doe, John |
 | null      |
 | null      |
 | null      |
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein This is the error. Sqlite exception: near "a": syntax error (code 1): while compiling: UPDATE person a, activity b SET value='attended' WHERE a.name = b.name

Comment: I think the error is in the alias usage. I'm not expect in android sqlite, but i think you can't use UPDATE TABLE ALIAS like you're trying to do

Comment: @Stefano I've tried this. db.execSQL("UPDATE person SET value= (SELECT name FROM activity WHERE  person.name = acitivty.name"); But it only gets the name not the value 'attended'. How to make it update using string 'attended'?

Comment: @Nube1Nu2 i don't know if you can do a multiple-tables update in a single command with sqlite.. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/329409/2003114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite only support single-table [update](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

The query can be converted to :

```
UPDATE person SET value = 'attended'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity.name = person.name)
```

this query updates only rows if there is a matching `activity`

Alternatively a modified version of your second query :

```
UPDATE person SET value= (SELECT 'attended' FROM activity WHERE person.name = activity.name)
```

updates every row with either `'attended'` or `null`

Comment: Why does other values displayed as null if acitivity.name is not equal to person.name?

Comment: I guessed wrong. I edited the first query and added a second based on your second query

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UPDATE with aliases in that way.

Remove aliases or, if you want to keep them, be sure to respect the correct sqlite grammar. Example on aliases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225925/sqlite-alias-column-name-cant-contains-a-dot)